# Restore deleted files on GCS, versioning off?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Accidentally we deleted some images files from our GCS bucket which didn't have the "versioning" activated (it was OFF).

Is it still a way we could restore these deleted files?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no.

GCS objects generally cannot be recovered after being permanently deleted by a user.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to restore a deleted object unless versioning is enabled on a bucket.